# ElasticSearch Range Query based on another field

Tags: elasticsearch

So the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-range-query.html) always use arbitrary dates as the value to check against.

if I have an object which has these properties on:

```
DateTime DueDate
DateTime NotRequired
```

How do I do something like this:

```
{
    "range" : {
        "NotRequired" : {
            "gt" : "DueDate"
        }
    }
}
```

So effectively giving you simple query of get me all entities where `NotRequired > DueDate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`range` queries only accept specific values. But you can achieve what you want by using a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) which would compare both dates.

```
"bool" : {
    "filter" : {
        "script" : {
            "script" : "doc.NotRequired.date > doc.DueDate.date"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in order for this to work you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).